# How can I write this code to plot the background color correctly useing arrays?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to wrap my head around arrays. This is modified script from tradingview shared indicator for Williams Fractals. I asked ChatGPT to code the script so it would show green background highlighted and red background highlited when the highs and lows coinside with a change in price dirrection. The problem is there are no errors in the code but it is not printing the background. Can I get help understanding why the arrays are not registering as values which allow the background to change color?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Williams Fractals", shorttitle="Fractals", format=format.price, precision=0, 
overlay=true)

// Define "n" as the number of periods and keep a minimum value of 2 for error handling.
n = input.int(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2)

// Arrays to store fractal values
var float[] upFractalHighs = array.new_float(n)
var float[] upFractalLows = array.new_float(n)
var float[] downFractalHighs = array.new_float(n)
var float[] downFractalLows = array.new_float(n)

// UpFractal
bool upflagDownFrontier = true
bool upflagUpFrontier0 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier1 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier2 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier3 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier4 = true

for i = 1 to n
    upflagDownFrontier := upflagDownFrontier and (high[n-i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier0 := upflagUpFrontier0 and (high[n+i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier1 := upflagUpFrontier1 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 1] < 
high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier2 := upflagUpFrontier2 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= 
high[n] and high[n+i + 2] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier3 := upflagUpFrontier3 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= 
high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 3] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier4 := upflagUpFrontier4 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= 
high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+4] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 4] < high[n])
flagUpFrontier = upflagUpFrontier0 or upflagUpFrontier1 or upflagUpFrontier2 or 
upflagUpFrontier3 or upflagUpFrontier4

upFractal = (upflagDownFrontier and flagUpFrontier)

// Store the values of the most recent and second most recent up fractals
array.push(upFractalHighs, upFractal ? high[0] : na)
array.push(upFractalLows, upFractal ? low[0] : na)
mostRecentUpHigh = array.last(upFractalHighs)
mostRecentUpLow = array.last(upFractalLows)
secondMostRecentUpHigh = array.get(upFractalHighs, 1)
secondMostRecentUpLow = array.get(upFractalLows, 1)

// downFractal
bool downflagDownFrontier = true
bool downflagUpFrontier0 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier1 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier2 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier3 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier4 = true

for i = 1 to n
    downflagDownFrontier := downflagDownFrontier and (low[n-i] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier0 := downflagUpFrontier0 and (low[n+i] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier1 := downflagUpFrontier1 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 1] 
> low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier2 := downflagUpFrontier2 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= 
low[n] and low[n+i + 2] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier3 := downflagUpFrontier3 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= 
low[n] and low[n+3] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 3] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier4 := downflagUpFrontier4 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= 
low[n] and low[n+3] >= low[n] and low[n+4] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 4] > low[n])
flagDownFrontier = downflagUpFrontier0 or downflagUpFrontier1 or downflagUpFrontier2 or 
downflagUpFrontier3 or downflagUpFrontier4

downFractal = (downflagDownFrontier and flagDownFrontier)

// Store the values of the most recent and second most recent down fractals
array.push(downFractalHighs, downFractal ? high[0] : na)
array.push(downFractalLows, downFractal ? low[0] : na)
mostRecentDownHigh = array.last(downFractalHighs)
mostRecentDownLow = array.last(downFractalLows)
secondMostRecentDownHigh = array.get(downFractalHighs, 1)
secondMostRecentDownLow = array.get(downFractalLows, 1)

// Determine if the most recent fractal is higher than the second most recent for both 
up and down fractals
isHigherHighUp = mostRecentUpHigh > secondMostRecentUpHigh and mostRecentUpLow > 
secondMostRecentUpLow
isHigherHighDown = mostRecentDownHigh > secondMostRecentDownHigh and mostRecentDownLow > 
secondMostRecentDownLow

// Set background color based on conditions
bgcolor(isHigherHighUp ? color.new(#14e61b, 41) : isHigherHighDown ? color.new(#e01e1e, 
34) : na)

// Plot green and red triangles
plotshape(downFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-n, 
color=isHigherHighDown ? color.red : #F44336, size = size.small)
plotshape(upFractal, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.abovebar, offset=-n, 
color=isHigherHighUp ? color.green : #009688, size = size.small)
```